# Three.js - antialiasing, rendering, fxaa

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, render

I have a three.js project with 3d-models, a ground and a grid in it. 
The 3d-models getting outlined with outlinePass (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=outl#webgl_postprocessing_outline).

I am able to move the objects with Transformcontrol (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=transf#misc_controls_transform) and i can change my camera position with Orbitcontrols (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=orbit#misc_controls_orbit)

The problem: The graphics seem kind of badly rendered, here some screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxjrZ.jpg

I don't really know which settings i should use here:

```
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();//{ antialias: true } ); With antialiasing or without?
                                 //antialiasing is only needed when not using fxaa, right??
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            renderer.gammaOutput = true;
            renderer.physicallyCorrectLights = true;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, container.offsetWidth / container.offsetHeight, 0.001, 1000 );
    camera.addEventListener( 'change', render ); //Is this necessary? Seems like it has no use
```

FXAA is probably necessary for outlinePass (also in the outlinePass-example linked above).

```
    composer = new EffectComposer( renderer );

            var renderPass = new RenderPass( scene, camera );
            composer.addPass( renderPass );

            effectFXAA = new ShaderPass( FXAAShader );
            effectFXAA.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.set( 1 / window.innerWidth, 1 / window.innerHeight );
            effectFXAA.renderToScreen = true;
            composer.addPass( effectFXAA );   

            orbitControls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            orbitControls.update();
            orbitControls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

    function render(){
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    //composer.render(); // don't know if needed
    }
```

So i have to say, i have not really a clue how i can solve the rendering issue and which settings i have to set to make the most out of my project. I'm happy for every hint and answers and maybe i can put these answers together and solve the issue.

Answer (score 6):

When using post-processing with WebGL 1, you have to use FXAA for antialiasing. Passing `{ antialias: true }` to `true` when creating `WebGLRenderer` activates MSAA but only if you render to the default framebuffer (directly to screen).

In any event, you configure the FXAA pass like so:

```js
effectFXAA = new ShaderPass( FXAAShader );
effectFXAA.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.x = 1 / ( window.innerWidth * pixelRatio );
effectFXAA.uniforms[ 'resolution' ].value.y = 1 / ( window.innerHeight * pixelRatio );
composer.addPass( effectFXAA );
```

You have to honor the `pixelRatio`. Besides, setting `renderToScreen` to `true` is not necessary anymore. The last pass in the post-processing chain is automatically rendered to screen now.

When using `EffectComposer`, you do not call `renderer.render(scene, camera);`. You have to use `composer.render();` instead.

`camera.addEventListener( 'change', render );` can also be deleted. I'm not sure where you seen this but it has no effect.

`three.js R109`

Comment: Thank your for all these informations! I changed my render settings to your suggestions, but now when i move the camera or move the object, it shakes very strong. I move my objects with transformcontrol and coded it like this:
control.addEventListener( 'change', render );

function render() {
    composer.render();
   }

Comment: Can you please try it with a normal animation loop? Like so: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/e0a31ea77c0242ae29ef6e951fa588216e1d247f/examples/webgl_postprocessing.html#L95-L102. You can then remove the `change` event listener from the controls.

Comment: i tried this and it works fine. No shaking at all.
Wow: i deleted the change event listeners of the transform and orbitcontrols and its not shaky anymore, are they not needed?

Comment: They are only necessary if you don't use an ongoing animation loop. It depends on the use case if an animation loop is actually required.

Comment: In this case i need the event listeners, but if i add them my program is very shaky, do you have aby advice?

Comment: Mugen do you have any idea? i have no clue why my program is so shaky when adding these two listeners. Also the bad rendering problem with this grid still exists :/

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate the effect with a live example? https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/ It might be related to the fact that the world matrix of the camera is not always up-to-date.

Comment: i unfortunately can't show the code. But if i delete the two Eventlisteners (transformcontrol.addEventListener( 'change', render ) and orbitcontrol.addEventListener( 'change', render )) it works fine and by adding them its feels like i have only 5 fps

Comment: I now know the issue with the grid. If i set mygrid.material.depthTest = false; its always visible. the new problem is thats its even visible through objects. I'm just trying to use renderorder to solve the issue but the same problems appear as shown in the imgur on my post.